# Running python application on Mac without installing python

Tags: python, macos

I am trying to create a python standalone application to run on Mac computer without installing python.

I tried - pyinstaller, cxfreeze and py2app without any luck.

I work on a windows computer and I know that for both pyinstaller and cxfreeze I need to use a Mac computer in order to create a file for mac. A student working with me who has a Mac tried those but had no luck.

I can create an exe. file that works perfect on windows so I know that is not something wrong with the code itself.

I need to have a Mac version as well because my target group in my research is mainly using Mac.

Comment: As for Pyinstaller, did you follow this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25469869/run-python-program-without-installing-required-modules

Comment: How about putting it in a docker image that can run on Windows, Linux and macOS?

Comment: @MarkSetchell don't you need a Docker executable for that? Kind of like you need the Java virtual machine for Java

Comment: @Pat-Laugh Not sure what you mean by *"a docker executable"*. You would need to install **docker**, yes, but OP doesn't express any objection to that, only to installing Python. If you want something consistently runnable across many platforms, docker is a good solution.

Comment: Alternatively, how about putting it in a *"free tier"* Amazon EC2 node that they can log into and use without installing any nasty Windows stuff on their lovely Macs? Or giving them a Windows virtual machine file with your Python code in, that they can run under VirtualBox - then, if they get unhappy with all that Windows stuff they can delete the whole lot just by removing a single file.

Comment: pyinstaller and cx_freeze should work on Mac. It's likely that your friend doesn't have all of the Python modules you use installed. If you read the output during "compiling" process there should be error messages saying which modules are missing. You may have to dump all of the compiling messages into a file to make sure you get them all (some terminals have a limited number lines they will retain by default)

Comment: Thank you for your answers! The idea is to avoid any software instillation of any kind (and have the subjects just download a zip folder with the executable file they need to run). We are using modules from Tkinter and currently we have a problem even when we try to create a simple executable that open a window in Tkinter. I am not familiar with windows virtual machine files -can they run the executable file I created on windows without having to install anything else in this way?

Answer (score 0):

from [here](https://docs.python.org/2/using/mac.html#:%7E:text=Mac%20OS%20X%2010.8%20comes,PPC%20CPU%27s%2C%20is%20available%20there.):

> Mac OS X 10.8 comes with Python 2.7 pre-installed by Apple. If you wish, you are invited to install the most recent version of Python from the Python website (https://www.python.org). A current “universal binary” build of Python, which runs natively on the Mac’s new Intel and legacy PPC CPU’s, is available there.

**edit**:
Also see [here](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) for the PyInstaller

Comment: Not sure how it helps to suggest installing Python when OP's question explicitly states that is to be avoided?

Comment: Because you don't need to install anything on Mac OS - it comes pre-installed by Apple - the downside is that OP needs to keep the Python version of the code at 2.7.